# Create a new version of the application in Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-version

Last week I created the 1.0 version of my application and I have uploaded Google play. One day later, the application was removed due to copyright. I have made the regulations and I want to upload them again.

To upload a new version onto the app in Google Play, the APKs that are installed must have the same SHA1 values.

[image]

My Application V1.0 SHA1 value image that I have already installed is also seen.

[image]

I want to create a V2.0 version with the same SHA1 value. I searched a lot of resources but I did not find any effective results. I am waiting for help from experienced people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. 
-> First I made the version number 2.0

[image]

Distribute -> Ad Hoc

[image]

Select keystore of your first application -> Save As

This step is out of sight because, we must change apk name (com.cr.myapp_2)

[image]

Lastly create same SHA1 values with new version.